# Classe android para dispara eventos, Rotina Batch?

Tags: java, android, batch

Necessito de uma classe que, de tempos em tempos, tente cruzar dados do banco de dados e dependendo do resultado enviar uma notificação ao usuário ou modificar/incluir informações do banco. Não sei se essa classe/estrutura ficaria dentro do escopo do app, empacotado no sdk no celular do usuário ou se é algo externo... Como faço isso? Qual é o recurso que se utiliza pra esse tipo de atividade?

Comment: Acho que é melhor o backend fazer essa tarefa e enviar a notificação

Comment: Onde vc colocaria essa classe de controle? Como faria pra ela ser disparada? N sei como lidar com ações que não é o usuário que dispara no android. Já que n haveria interface para interação, n sei qual é o recurso utilizado pra isso.

Answer (score 0):

Podes criar um service com um alarmManager que faz uma ligação ao servidor para consultar alterações mas isso irá aumentar muito o consumo de energia e dados do telemóvel, a melhor alternativa é ser o servidor a enviar quando existe alterações e para isso podes usar o Firebase Messaging, é um serviço gratuito e extremamente rápido.